Reusable Components and intercommunication for both web and mobile
Looking for an answer from a well experienced high-level React Native architect.
I want to have a setup that's workable across both Web and Mobile for a Master Detail Flow.
Universal, Unified kind of setup.
Current Implementation: Mobile Setup: One screen is displayed at a time. UserList is displayed and tapping an item navigates to UserDetail and populates the details.
Question: Desktop/Browser Setup: Expectation is that both UserList and UserDetail are displayed simultaneously on a page (no navigation) and UserDetail gets populated.

App.js
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="UserList">
        <Stack.Screen name="UserList" component={UserList} options={{ title: 'User List' }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="UserDetail" component={UserDetail} options={{ title: 'User Details' }} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

UserList.js
const UserList = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Simulating an API call
    setUsers([
      { id: '1', name: 'John Doe', email: 'john@example.com' },
      { id: '2', name: 'Jane Smith', email: 'jane@example.com' },
      { id: '3', name: 'Emily Davis', email: 'emily@example.com' },
    ]);
  }, []);

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.item}
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate('UserDetail', { user: item })}
    >
      <Text style={styles.name}>{item.name}</Text>
      <Text>{item.email}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={users}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
  },
  item: {
    padding: 20,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#ccc',
  },
  name: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

export default UserList;

UserDetail
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const UserDetail = ({ route }) => {
  const { user } = route.params;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.label}>ID: {user.id}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.label}>Name: {user.name}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.label}>Email: {user.email}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 18,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
});

export default UserDetail;

